# New file created in Xcode 9.3, <wsname>.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist should it be committed?

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I downloaded the newly released Xcode 9.3, I recompiled my workspace and I noticed it produced a new file:

`<mywsname>.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist`

whose contents are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>IDEDidComputeMac32BitWarning</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I wonder if this file should be git ignored or committed. I was not able to find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 211):

From 9.3 release notes, it sounds like you'd want to commit.

> Xcode 9.3 adds a new IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist file to a workspace’s
>   shared data, to store the state of necessary workspace checks.
>   Committing this file to source control will prevent unnecessary
>   rerunning of those checks for each user opening the workspace.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-DontLinkElementID_7)

Comment: Additionally it's located in the xc**shared**data which can be treated as common code for fellow devs.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I had searched the notes, but I searched for the key and not for the filename. Looks like committing it is the "right" thing to do in most cases.

Comment: What should developer do to prevent this 32bit Warning?

Comment: Wonder how this interplays with tools like Cocoapods that regenerate the Workspace all the time?