# IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist file suddenly appear after updated xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I suddenly start having this file in my xcode project after I updated my xcode:

```
myProject.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist
```

What does this file do? Should I exclude it in version control?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49564513/2266462

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New file created in Xcode 9.3, <wsname>.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist should it be committed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564513/new-file-created-in-xcode-9-3-wsname-xcworkspace-xcshareddata-ideworkspaceche)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can take a look on the [Xcode release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html)

> Xcode 9.3 adds a new IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist file to a workspace's shared data, to store the state of necessary workspace checks. Committing this file to source control will prevent unnecessary rerunning of those checks for each user opening the workspace. (37293167)

It's good to commit it to your repository.